# Print out the content of the list with order number in the front

Tags: python, database, list, list-comprehension

I'm wondering if I have a list such as

```
['Jim', 'Nora', 'Jacob', 'May']
```

but I actually have a really long list (more than 300 items in it) and my desired output is something like this:

```
1. Jim
2. Nora
3. Jacob
4. May
```

Print out all the items in the list with the order number (start from 1, and the "." after the number is required) in the list (no hard-coding). How can I achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```py
names = ['Jim', 'Nora', 'Jacob', 'May']
for idx, name in enumerate(names):
    print(f"{idx+1}. {name}")
```

---

Edit:
Or the cleaner:

```
names = ['Jim', 'Nora', 'Jacob', 'May']
for idx, name in enumerate(names, start=1):
    print(f"{idx}. {name}")
```

Comment: You could just do `enumerate(names, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

A list compression approach, if you actually need the entire output string as a single piece:

```py
inp = ['Jim', 'Nora', 'Jacob', 'May']
output = '\n'.join([str(x+1) + '. ' + inp[x] for x in range(len(inp))])
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
1. Jim
2. Nora
3. Jacob
4. May
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list *enumerate*.

```
lst = ['Jim', 'Nora', 'Jacob', 'May']
for number, name in enumerate(lst,1):
    print(str(number)+'.', name)
```

[**Output**]

```
1. Jim
2. Nora
3. Jacob
4. May
```